# TV Shows DVDs with Extras

Tags: dvd-release, television, interviews, documentary

This is a long stretch but I'm wondering if there are any dvds of TV shows with sound design/editing/mixing extras. Interviews or making of docus would be awesome, but even a commentary would be great too. I know film dvds have quite a number, but I'm trying to do some research on broadcast and am coming up pretty empty handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Lost DVDs (can't remember which season... probably 1 or 2) has some extra material about sound... But it's extremely brief if I remember correctly

Comment: Yep, they were going over the foley and ADR sessions and how they do the workflow for production.  I think it was season 3 or so... some "a day of production" featurette.

Comment: Awesome! will go suss this out. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Tak there are also some Webinars covering the sound of Lost on the Avid website - http://apps.avid.com/dream-big-sleep-well/webinar_archive.asp

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few DVD box sets that include interviews, "making of"s and commentaries, but most tend to focus on the sets, costumes, background, character development, etc - in fact, just about everything except the sound!

There are a few that come to mind as standing out (to me, at least) from the rest:

1. Firefly - includes an interesting "making of"
2. Fringe (Season 1) - contains some nice background and clever extras
3. Lie To Me (Season 1) - includes an informative documentary
4. Whitechapel  (UK mini-series) - also includes an informative documentary
5. ... OK, my mind just went blank (will check through my collection & add more if I get a chance)

Comment: Thanks for that! I was wondering about the box sets couldn't find anything relating to sound just as you said. Sigh...